# dissplay only the words that have a given length - string php

Tags: php, string

Example:

```
a
aaa
aaaaa
aaa
aa
```

If given length is 3 then it should show:

```
aaa
aaa
```

I have:

```
$words = explode(" ", $_POST['txt']);
for ($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++){ 
echo $words[$i] . " ";
```

Can this be done with foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$words = explode(" ", $_POST['txt']);
$length = 3;

foreach($words as $word) {
    // mb_strlen to take multibyte characters into account
    if(mb_strlen($word) == $length) {
        echo $word . "\n";
    }
}
```

Maybe?

Comment: trim is not needed as the explode eliminates the spaces

Comment: in this scenario only. because you explode by space. so space cannot exist at start or end of an element. if you explode by e.g. "," spaces will be exist. just wanted to make it clear, because as obvious as it is, it seemed like you confused :)

Comment: Yeah, didn't read your comment as thorough as I should have :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
$length = 3;
$words = explode(" ", $_POST['txt']);

foreach ($words as $word) {
  if (strlen($word) == $length) {
    echo $word . ' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: you missed the new line in output :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `foreach`. However, if `$words` are an array, you could leverage one of the array functions like [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$length = 3;
$words = array_filter($words, function($word) use ($length) {
  return mb_strlen($word) == $length;
});
print_r($words);
```

**Note:** Requires PHP 5.3+.